# TokenRegex File file not found error

Tags: java, eclipse, hierarchy, stanford-nlp

When I compile my code, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: tr.txt (No such file or directory)
```

This is my file structure.

```
MrProject
├── tr.txt
├── pom.xml
└── src
   └── main
      ├── java
      │   └── com
      │      └── nlp
      │         └── myapp
      │            └── MyClaa.java
      └── webapp
         ├── MyTest.html
         └── WEB-INF
             └── web.xml
```

`tr.txt` is the TokenRegex file that MyClass.java is using to read the rules off of. When I make a project (in eclipse) that is not a web project, then I do not get this is error (with the same hierarchy of files except there is no web app folder, pom.xml, and all of the other web project related folder and files). But when I do this in a web project, I get this error (with the above project hierarchy).

What hierarchy does the `tr.txt` have to be in?

Thanks a lot for your help and I appreciate it!

Comment: At the top of your `main()` method, add this line of code: `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());` . This will tell you where your relative paths are based on.

Comment: Since this is in my server, the file path is completely different: `/var/lib/[...]/wildfly/` The file path is different from my local one. So what do you think I should do?

Comment: You should copy the TokensRegex file to an absolute path and load the file from that path. Or, you should include the file in your built jar/war, and then use the classpath (e.g., "edu/stanford/nlp/tr.txt") as the path to the file.

Comment: One way to solve this is to add src/main/resources/edu/stanford/nlp/tr.txt to your project, and in your code refer to the file with "edu/stanford/nlp/tr.txt"

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp would I have to use maven to include it in my war/build path?

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp The solution worked. Thank you for answer!